# Print html pages with page-break

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

i have data for create table and print it. The structure is like :

Title
Data
Sum

The title must not be at the end of page and the Sum must not be at the start of page when print it. Thant is why i made html table with Divs and give all size with mm. but i couldnt colculate when break page. couse in different computers height changes.

here is my javascript code for calculate and break page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var mydiv ='<div class="page-break"></div>';
        var i=0;
        var h = px2cm($("#myinfo").last().height())*10;
        var limit=297;
        var g =0;

        $('#content div.ptr').each(function(){
            g=0;
            h = h + px2cm($(this).height())*10;
            var nexth=px2cm($(this).next().height())*10;
            if(h>=limit-nexth)
            {               
                if($(this).hasClass("ptrtitle")){
                    $(this).before(mydiv);
                    h = px2cm($(this).height())*10;
                    i++;
                    g=1;
                }else{                  
                    if(String($(this).next().attr("class"))==="ptr ptrsum"){
                        if($(this).prev().hasClass("ptrtitle"))
                        {
                            $(this).prev().before(mydiv);
                            h = px2cm($(this).height()+$(this).prev().height())*10;
                        }else{
                            $(this).before(mydiv);
                            h = px2cm($(this).height())*10;
                        }
                        //h=0;
                        i++;
                        g=1;
                    }else{
                            $(this).after(mydiv);
                            h=0;i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function px2cm(px) {
      var d = $("<div/>").css({ position: 'absolute', top : '-1000cm', left : '-1000cm', height : '1000cm', width : '1000cm' }).appendTo('body');
      var px_per_cm = d.height() / 1000;
      d.remove();
      return px / px_per_cm;
    }
```

here i add limit=297(for A4 height, it works good on some computers, but doesnt work good on others). doesnt work good means that, on the first computer it prints 40 row in one page, but on another some rows go to the next print page

How can i normally print data in all computers

Comment: Have you looked at the CSS property page-break-inside? Perhaps you could add it to the div and set it to 'avoid'.

Comment: yes but i doesnt work

Comment: It might be easier for us to help if you created a simple demo of your markup in a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: i couldn't understand that, in this example i set a 257(297-40(margin)) mm height width div, it must take whole page but it took part of it    [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1cj0a2zn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css2 property `page-break` for your class `page-break` with `@media print` instead of calculating page break manually. Also different scale can be used specific to `print` if needed.

```
@media print {
    .page-break {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

Comment: i have already add this class.  problem is that after title and before sum rows div must not break, and page-break-after: avoid doesnt work work divs